# Is it possible to register a connection adapter to multiple prefixes using Python requests.Session?

Tags: python, python-requests

Is it possible register an `Adapter` to both `http` and `https` like:

```
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

session = Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[403, 404, 502, 503, 504])
session.mount("http", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

session.get(api_url)
```

or do I need to register individually for both?

```
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

session = Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[403, 404, 502, 503, 504])
session.mount("http://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
session.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

session.get(api_url)
```